# My App Engine app is showing way more write ops than expected. How can I diagnose what's going on?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

95% of my app costs are related to write operations. In the last few days I've paid $150. And I wouldn't consider the amount of data stored to be that huge.

First I suspected that there may be a lot of write operations because of exploding indexes, but I read that this situation usually happens when you have two list properties in the same model. But during the model design phase those were limited to 1 per model max.

I also did try to go through my models and pass indexed=False to all properties that I will not need to order or filter by.

One other thing that I would need to disclose about my app is that I have bundled write operations in the sense that there are some entities that when they need to be stored, I usually call a proxy function that stores that entity and derivative entities along with it. Not in a transactional way since it's not a big deal if there's a write failure every now and then. But I don't really see a way around that given the logic of how the models are related.

So I'm eager to hear if someone else faced that problem and which approach / tools /etc they followed to solve it. Or if there are just some general things one can do..

Answer (score 7):

You can try [appstats tool](http://code.google.com/intl/en/appengine/docs/java/tools/appstats.html). It can show you datastore calls stats, etc.